# Find a closed formula for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $A(n, m)$ be functions on $\mathbb{N}^2$ such that $A(n, 0)=n$ and $A(m, n)=A(n, m)$ and that 
$$
A(m, n)=\frac{mA(m-1, n)+n A(m, n-1)}{m+n}.
$$
Question: Is there a closed formula for $A(n, n)$?

(This question arises when I do algorithmic exercises.）

Comment: Perhaps generating functions can help? I might look at this again tonight, when I'm at my computer, but I doubt it.

Comment: Seems to be $2n/(n+1)$. That's just from computing a few values.